# How to show the number in ManyToManyField appear as number but not ediatbale

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How I can show the number of `models.ManyToManyField` as a number but not editable because when I set `editable=False` I couldn't see the number of users in the Django model

like this

```
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(Account, editable=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `readonly_fields` in **admin.py**

```
admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    readonly_fields = ['id','viewers']
```